# Group operation continuous in the interval topology

Tags: group-theory, topological-groups

I'm trying to prove the following:
We have a DLO without endpoints M, 
and a group operation on M, which is continuous in the interval topology.
I want to prove: if $b<c$ then for every $a \in M$ we have that $b+a<c+a$.

I'm trying to consider the supremum, defined for a fixed $a \in M$: $s:=sup \{ x| x+a<b+a \}$, and show that we must have $s=b$, but since this is an arbitrary DLO I can't have $s \in M$ so I'm a bit stuck.
any ideas?

Thanks!